# Как посчитать количество комментариев к каждой статье в Django

Tags: django

[image: образец]
views.py
подскажите как написать код, заранее спасибо

```
def articles(request, article_id):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
    comments_sum = Comments.objects.values('comments_article_id').count()
    return render_to_response('articles.html', {'articles': queryset,    
   'article1': comments_sum})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "article"
    article_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    article_text = models.TextField()
    article_date = models.DateTimeField()
    article_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    article_comment_sum = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.article_title

class Comments(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "comments"
    comments_text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Поле комментария')
    comments_article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_comments_sum = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comments_text
```

Comment: Код моделей покажите.

Answer (score 0):

Поля `article_comment_sum` не нужны. Просто аннотируйте `QuerySet` результатом [агрегатной функции](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
articles = Articles.objects.annotate(comments_count=Count('comments_set')).all()
```

**P.S.** Именовать модели принято в единственном числе

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а что за поле 'comments_set' я совсем недавно изучаю джанго и не очень пока понимаю. пишет ошибку:  Cannot resolve keyword 'comments_set'

Comment: Это [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects), который ORM создаёт, если на модель ссылается другая модель. Ошибка не должна возникать.

Comment: нет, он принял только Count('comments') , а Count('comments_set') , ругался , что нет такой  Cannot resolve keyword 'comments_set'

Comment: Значит у вас атрибут `relative_name` указан в `ForeignKey`.

Comment: class Comments(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "comments"
    comments_text = models.TextField(verbose_name='Поле комментария')
    comments_article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article_comments_sum = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comments_text

Comment: вроде бы после CASCADE у меня нет related_name= , у меня просто : comments_article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  я просто извиняюсь разбираюсь, хочу для себя понять.. в любом случае, огромное спасибо , помогли с annotate

Comment: @xxxxxx [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).